# How to send integer to pointer of type id

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, integer

This may be a simple question for some. For me its a headache. How to send an integer as an id object in this method:

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestImageAtIndex:) withObject:index waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Index is the integer here.

Thank you all in advance.

P.S. "There are no dumb questions, there are only dumb answers." Marshall Loeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap it in `NSNumber` object ?

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestImageAtIndex:)
                       withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It was an easy and quick solution. Plus a really fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

To pass plain values in this situation you need to wrap them into some objective-c objects. In your case NSNumber will work (of course `requestImageAtIndex` method must take `NSNumber` object as parameter to make it work):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestImageAtIndex:)
                       withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int index;

index=5;



[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestImageAtIndex:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] waitUntilDone:NO];


-(void)requestImageAtIndex:(NSNumber*)number{

    int i=[number intValue];

}
```